# Microsoft Flow column lookup still failing

Tags: sharepoint-online, flow

I have an InfoPath form on which workflows via MS Flow were working nicely until I added more lookup columns (namely, People Picker fields).

I did the prescribed workaround in Flow - choosing a view in which the lookup fields were fewer than the admin limit of 12. Even when I reduce the number of lookup columns in this view to 1, the workflow still doesn't work and I get this error:

*The query cannot be completed because the number of lookup columns it contains exceeds the lookup column threshold enforced by the administrator*

I am not an admin and I can only use OOB solutions.

Comment: Can you share your query in workflow ?